# Sails js body parser doesn't work

Tags: parsing, sails.js

I am using Sails JS and Postman to POST on '/register' with following JSON data in the Body (raw):

```
{
    username: "abc",
    password: "abc"
}
```

In my routes I defined the controller

```
'post /register': 'AuthController.register'
```

**but** I can't get the body params in the right format.

```
console.log(req.body);
```

creates this log:

```
{ '{\n\tusername: "abc",\n\tpassword: "abc"\n}': '' }
```

which is not valid JSON. SailsJs Doc says that the body parser should already be included. Why can't I access the right body parameters then?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Postman needs to escape the JSON key with " aswell.

Thus, send

```
{
    "username": "abc",
    "password": "abc"
}
```

This took way too long to find..